# Is there any reference app available for learning react native?

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native. I want to develop a app with login feature, is there any good reference app available to learn react native?

Comment: I would suggest using official documentation from react native.
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

.And for more reference, you can learn from udemy. https://www.udemy.com/react-native-the-practical-guide/learn/v4/overview

Answer (score 1):

Udemy is a good place to start to learn react native.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends on your existing skills.

If you know React, Javascript and familiar with full-stack WEB development then I would suggest

1. [The Complete React Native + Hooks Course [2020 Edition]](https://www.udemy.com/course/the-complete-react-native-and-redux-course/) - by Stephen Grider
2. [React Native - The Practical Guide [2021 Edition]](https://www.udemy.com/course/react-native-the-practical-guide/)- by Maximilian Schwarzmüller
   Both these courses are current and updated as of this month. Suggest do take them in this order since Stephen will develop your fundamentals through projects and Maximilian will cover the detailed edge cases. Both are on Udemy and awesome to learn React Native from the ground up.

In case you are new to development then definitely try out [The Complete 2021 Web Development Bootcamp](https://www.udemy.com/course/the-complete-web-development-bootcamp/) - by Dr Angela Yu first before you dive into React Native.

Happy Learning!!